# RegionUtils.getRegionsForService("eks") returns empty list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-eks

We are trying to fetch the list of regions supporting EKS service on AWS using `RegionUtils.getRegionsForService(AmazonEKS.ENDPOINT_PREFIX)` API of its Java SDK. However, an empty list of Regions is returned. This API works perfectly for S3, EC2, etc. EKS is as of today supported in Northern Virginia, Oregon & Ireland.

Is it is currently not supported for EKS? An alternative here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The current SDK is reading from static file [`endpoints.json`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/resources/com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json), and this file is having no details for EKS. Here is the source [code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/aaa0a6f506314d314a77774ddadd303cf6e4c354/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/partitions/PartitionsLoader.java) for the same.

You can raise a bug in github repo.

Comment: Thanks, I had checked the repo before writing this question.